# Game AI OO Framework

Tags: frameworks, artificial-intelligence

Is there an artificial intelligence (AI) programming framework for game software engineers? I'm specifically looking for a library of object-oriented classes that I can use in a game. Specifically, I would like to know the best way to program NPC decision making that is purely object oriented. I have googled and gotten a lot of useless links to machine learning and theoretical AI websites that have absolutely nothing to do with practical software engineering. Any frameworks I've found are all either out of date or too academic to be useful. Specifically, I'm looking for Java or Objective-C libraries.

Comment: you should list what you've encountered so far. So that no answer repeat what you already have.

Comment: http://aigamedev.com/ Has a bunch of articles on AI middleware and an active IRC channel where you can ask.

Comment: I was hoping someone or group was working on one, a real framework, that was the real reason for my question.

Comment: The guys at aigamedev *are* working on one, a real framework, seriously... See forums/articles/IRC.

Comment: What kind of "decision making" are you interested in?  Do you want a simple FSM type architecture, something goal based, a reflex agent that acts based on a given percept sequence?  "Decision making" is a bit vague.  If you let me know what you're trying to accomplish with your AI, I might be able to suggest something.

Comment: I'm looking for a programming framework, not algorithms in the sense of procedural algorithms like an FSM, but like Java Server Faces, Ruby on Rails or a Zend Framework. I'm looking for OO frameworks that utilize software design patterns, but are designed with Artificial Intelligence in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for AI middleware/frameworks? Here's bunch:

[AI Implant](http://www.presagis.com/products_services/products/ms/simulation/aiimplant/more/aiimplant_for_games/)

[GRIP Character Control System](http://www.gripent.com/index_files/ProductsEN.htm)

[AI Gamedev Sandbox](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/hard-earned-insights/) (as was already mentioned in the comments, requires premium access)

[Kynapse](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=11390544&siteID=123112)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_AI_middleware) also lists bunch of other AI middleware, but these were the ones I have some experience in.

Comment: AI Sandbox at http://aisandbox.com/ sounds promising. I especially like the MVC framework idea. Thanks.